# "algaworks" - BigDecimal - Soma de valores

Tags: java, jsf, java-ee

Estou tentando somar os valores adicionados na coluna "Valor", ou seja, a cada inserção de uma receita o campo total abaixo precisa atualizar fazendo a soma dos valores na coluna valor, porem estou com o tipo BigDecimal, sendo assim não consigo fazer a soma e na view não aparece resultado nenhum, apenas o outputLabel value="Total RECEITA" que é a string.

Model:

```
@NotNull
@DecimalMin("0")
@Column(precision = 10, scale = 2, nullable = false)
private BigDecimal valor;

get e set
```

Este método esta na classe Lancamento (model)

```
@Transient
public void valorTotal(Lancamento lancamento) {
    BigDecimal total = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    total = total.add(this.getValor());
    this.setValor(total);
}
```

Enum

```
RECEITA("Receita"), 
DESPESA("Despesa");

get e set
```

Na View:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{consultaLancamentosBean.lancamentos}" var="lancamento">

<p:column>
<p:outputLabel value="Total RECEITA:" style="font-weight: bold; text-align: right; font-size: 1.1em" />
    <h:outputText id="totalReceita" value="#{lancamento.valorTotal(lancamento)}">
        <f:convertNumber type="currency" />
    </h:outputText>
</p:column>
```

Outro problema:

```
Exibi.
<p:outputLabel value="Total RECEITA: />

Não exibi o valorTotal
<h:outputText value="#{lancamento.valorTotal(lancamento)}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Tem dois problemas no seu código:

1. Você não está retornando valor nenhum na sua função `valorTotal`
2. Sua lógica de cálculo do valor total está confusa, um método está calculando e alterando e ao mesmo tempo está exibindo em tela durante o carregamento

Enfim, para começar você deve retornar o valor no seu método utilizado no `outputText`:

```
@Transient
public BigDecimal getValorTotal(Lancamento lancamento) {
    BigDecimal total = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    return total.add(this.getValor());
}
```

E alterar para utilizar esse método:

```
<h:outputText value="#{lancamento.getValorTotal(lancamento)}" />
```

Sugiro você também refatorar para efetuar os cálculos antes do carregamento da tela nessa situação, para evitar um método agregar muitas responsabilidades.

Comment: Com esse método o valor não está sendo somado a cada inserção, ele somente está pegando valor que já esta na coluna valor, sem a adição de valores.

Answer (score 0):

1º - O seu método valorTotal está definido como VOID. Sendo assim, você não pode usar o método para retornar o valor no outputext;

2- Outro problema é que você zera o valor da variável local total e depois adiciona this.valor() - Isso não faz sentido algum - .

Você passa um lançamento no seu método - getValorTotal(Lancamento lancamento) -  provavelmente será ele o cara que você quer manipular ou adicionar valores;